# Breaking array,into table view

Tags: iphone, arrays, ipad

I have an array,something like below

```
MutableArray (
        {
        "a" = 1;
        "b" = "";
        "c" = " ";
        "imagepath" = "../images/image.png";
        "d" = "dummy text";
        "e" = 2;
        "f" = "dummy text";
        "g" = dummy text;
        "h" = dummy text;
        "i" = "Feb 19, 2010";
    },
        {
        "a" = 2;
        "b" = "dummy";
        "c" = "dummy";
        "imagepath" = "../images/noimage.png";
        "d" = "dummy text";
        "e" = 3;
        "f" = "dummy text";
        "g" = dummy text;
        "h" = dummy text;
        "i" = "Mar 23 , 2010";
    })
```

What exactly i am trying is to get the values separately from the array like

```
row 1 : Title a,
row 2 : Title b,
row 3 : title c,
```

i want each values from the array separately.

I have table view, custom cell, with image and labels already created.
for ex Row 1 =  data from index 1
row 2= data from index 2
 something like that.
I m not sure how to get separates values from the array and put it in table row's labels.

Kindly suggest,how can i do that.

Comment: but do u want to seperate it. Use [array count] as section and fill data according to section as it will have dict = [array objectAtIndex:section.indexPath].

Comment: I am trying dynamically fill the rows's label like cell.lblNm.text =row 1's index 1 and so on ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Try getting values using KVC

// Paste this in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

```
    id key;
    NSDictionary *theDictionary = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    id value;
    for (key in [theDictionary allKeys])
    {
        value = [theDictionary objectForKey:key];
        // do something with the value
    NSLog(@"key: %@, value: %@", key, [theDictionary objectForKey:key]);
    }
Or else Try this

NSDictionary *theDictionary = [yourMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"key: a, value: %@", , [theDictionary objectForKey:@"a"]);
NSLog(@"key: b, value: %@", , [theDictionary objectForKey:@"b"]);
NSLog(@"key: c, value: %@", , [theDictionary objectForKey:@"c"]);
// So on ...
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is an array, why not just use [objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method when building a tableView? You could also create a cell object, and make the array an array of those objects, then pull the values out of that.

Comment: for ex if i want to set cell.lblNm.text= ??  how can i ?

Comment: it would be NSArray* array = [mutableArrayName objectAtIndex:IndexPath.row], then cell.lblNm.text = (NSString*)[array objectAtIndex:indexThatTheTitleIsAt];

Comment: Its an mutable array actually.

Comment: I m getting bad excess on that.Not sure why.but checking.